# Sorting a list based on nested list object property

Tags: java

Need to sort a `List<Object>` based on some `nested List<Object> property`

I have below DTO

```
public class WalletDetailsDTO {

    private List<CreditDetailDTO> creditDetails;

}

public class CreditDetailDTO {

    private String sectionType;

    private BigDecimal totalAmount;

    private List<SectionDetailsDTO> sectionDetails;

}

public class SectionDetailsDTO {
    private String startDate;

    private String expiryDate;

    private BigDecimal amount;
}
```

Requirement is need to sort `List<CreditDetailDTO> creditDetails` based on `List<SectionDetailsDTO> sectionDetails` `startDate` property.

Comment: I can't imagine how such comparison would work. What if `sectionDetails` contains multiple objects? Do you take `startDate` of the first, avg of them, sum?

Comment: The `startDate` is a `String` representing a date. Sorting that as a `String` strongly depends on its format, which is it? ISO format, like `2019-07-19`? Otherwise make that class attribute a `LocalDate`, which `implements Comparable`.

Comment: How do two creditDetail with multiple sectionDetails compare to each other? Which sectionDetail's startDay matter?